# How to mention try-catch block in JavaCC grammar

Tags: java, parsing, parser-generator, javacc

I am trying to implement Error Reporting and Recovery in JavaCC grammar as given in 
http://javacc.java.net/doc/errorrecovery.html

After mentioning the code;

```
void Stm() :
{}
{
  try {
    (
      IfStm()
    |
      WhileStm()
    )
  catch (ParseException e) {
    error_skipto(SEMICOLON);
  }
}


void error_skipto(int kind) {
  ParseException e = generateParseException();  // generate the exception object.
  System.out.println(e.toString());  // print the error message
  Token t;
  do {
    t = getNextToken();
  } while (t.kind != kind);
    // The above loop consumes tokens all the way up to a token of
    // "kind".  We use a do-while loop rather than a while because the
    // current token is the one immediately before the erroneous token
    // (in our case the token immediately before what should have been
    // "if"/"while".
}
```

The file was not able to parse by JavaCC showing error at 'try' word and at the line

```
'void error_skipto(int kind)' .
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance

```
This is the error that is coming
```

[image]

Comment: What does "showing error at 'try' word" mean. What are the *exact* error messages you're seeing, and on which *exact* lines are they happening? Please remember when posting questions here that we can't see your screen from here, and that the only information we have is what you provide in your question. "showing error" is meaningless without knowing what that error is and the rest of the information you have about it. You'll get help much faster with the problems you encounter if youj give us the information with which to solve it when you post your question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are not using JavaCC, but JTB 1.3.2.

JTB presumably has its own parser for .jj grammar files, and it might be the case that JTB does not support try-catch as shown. In that case, using JavaCC on the same input should give you a different result.

Comment: Getting the JTB source code and looking at their grammar would show whether try-catch is supported. Also look for versions newer than 1.3.2.